# Ajax call does not execute PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have written a very basic PHP pagination class and I'm trying to load the content with jQuery Ajax $.post requests. My class has two functions, one displays the content and the other one the pagination. If I don't use jQuery, but only PHP, everything works fine. Once I try to use jQuery, my displayContent() function never gets called, but the createNav() one does its job just fine(I mean the page numbers are loaded).

Here is my js.
http://goo.gl/BUZH1

And here is my PHP:

```
if($action=='displayArticles') displayArticles();

    function displayArticles()
    {
            $content=new createPages(5,10);
            $content->displayContent();
            $content->createNav();
    }
```

And here is the PHP class I just created. It was too large to add it in here, but I saved the code in text format.
http://goo.gl/Lv9Wl

Comment: Do you have register_globals on? If not you should be using $_POST['action']. Really you should use $_POST['action'] anyway because register_globals is a dangerous security risk.

Comment: do you see any error in console...?

Comment: no errors in console at all. As I said, it's just the displayArticles() that doesn't get loaded through jQuery. The other function outputs what it is supposed to and the output is loaded through jQuery. If I use the class without jQuery/Ajax, everything works fine. I don't think I understand what you mean by that $_POST['action'] thing. I am not using a global variable. I am simply using a single processor file for most of my requests. This way, everything is organized.(at least I like to think so). Whenever I send a request to that large processor file, I make sure to add action as a param

Comment: so displayArticles() get's called for sure? Either you have a SQL error in displayContent() (you should check, it appears you're not handling errors) or the SQL call simply doesn't return any results

Comment: @AlexFl - $_POST is how you normally must access variables that are posted to your program unless you have a PHP setting on called register_globals, which would make $action a global variable. I don't think the error console matters. I believe your problem is on the PHP side. You could test this by making a simple form with no javascript but containing the same fields and try posting to it. Or check your server error_log. It may have errors in it

Comment: Ok i found the problem. Cfreak post it as an answer so that I can pick it as a valid answer. A small token of my appreciation for the time you have given me. The query is not returning any results indeed. I got the $this->startIndex initialized in the wrong way..

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping $_POST['action'], then check the output in the $.post response. It's pretty obvious that your if statement is resolving to false. :)

You can also try dumping $action, then checking that in the response. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You **can not** call PHP functions after the page has been loaded. PHP is server side script, so you need AJAX to load a separate page, where your `displayArticles` function will be defined.

Comment: It's a little confusing but I don't believe that's what he's doing. He's got a displayArticles() function in javascript that makes an AJAX request to a displayArticles() function in PHP